# If on the same page

Tags: cross-referencing

I would like to code a macro working like `\ref` with an additional function: if the argument is on the same page as the reference (the actual page) it adds `page \pageref`.

I tried to do it but I think I don't do it the right way. Here is my code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{reff}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\thepage = \pageref{#1}}%
    {\ref{#1}}%
    {\ref{#1} page \pageref{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{References}

The first test section \reff{test1} and the second test section \reff{test2}.

\section{\label{test1## Heading ##} Test section}

\newpage

\section{\label{test2} Second test section}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

It should display:

```
The first test section 2 and the second test section 3 page 2.
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before of reinvent the wheel, take a look to the `varioref` package  (i.e., run  `texdoc varioref`):

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{varioref}
\begin{document}
\section{References}
The first test section \vref{test1} 
and the second test section \vref{test2}.
\section{\label{test1} Test section}
\newpage
\section{\label{test2} Second test section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Fran, that is what I was looking for.